# I don't want datetimepicker setting default value on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text input to which I have applied a DateTimePicker plugin

But when I click on the input before opening the DateTimePicker, it sets default value as current date, I want the value to stay empty as long as the user selects it from the DateTimePicker.

```
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
});
```

The DateTimePicker Library which i am using is:
[eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker)

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried so far?

Comment: i try this
    $('.datepicker').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
         $(this).val("01/01/1980");
    });

    
    and
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        setValue:""
    });

Comment: Can you at least tell us which datetimepicker plugin you are using?  Bootstrap / jquery-ui / other?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the jquery, then it will be formatted - comments don't include formatting

Comment: jquery-ui datepicker, you might be able to onSelect and reset the dateText to the current input value (empty).  http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

Comment: is bootstrap library

Comment: are you using this library? 
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#minimum-setup
 If yes this will probably work out for you

` $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',useCurrent:false}); `

Comment: @AmoghHegde thankyou, it works

Comment: Welcome :)
@freedomn Can this question be removed from hold so that i can post it as an answer?

Comment: @WellintongAntonioSotoRamire I think you just need to set the value of the input field to empty string `""`

Comment: @AmoghHegde I can't un-hold it, there's a vote option to reopen if you have enough rep, but IMO the question itself could do with updating (adding the library for a start) first.

Comment: Ohh okk thanks for the clarification.. I have just started here today :)

Answer (score 3):

I have mentioned the answer in the comments above but just posting it as an Answer for someone who might face the same issue in the future

Initialize the DateTimePicker with `useCurrent` as `false` as shown below:

`$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',useCurrent:false});`